Why does it take so long to create a photo link on iPhone Photos?
Is there any way to make creating an iCloud link not take a long time?
It often takes 30 seconds to a minute or two to create an iCloud link even for a small number of photos, e.g. 5 photos.
I have an iPhone 11 Pro Max with iOs 18.0.1, but it’s been happening for a long time, on older versions of iOs as well.
I have 500+ MBPS upload and download, so slow internet is not the issue.
I also have Photos set to Optimize iPhone Storage to minimize local storage on my iPhone.
With google photos, you create a link almost immediately and can share that link. When people get the link, they can see the photos right away.
Thanks for any light you can share on this. It’s making me think about switching to Google Photos, though I have so much in Apple Photos that I’d prefer not to switch.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Several accounts based out of the US with much slower internet create these links in 1-2 second range reliably. Two things I can think of to check before you reach out to Apple support (who can look into the back end processing speed you have an issue with) are what region are your iCloud Photos stored (EU, US, Asia, Mainland china, other…) and where is your internet access based. It’s unlikely the delay is time to send the request and almost certainly processing speed at Apple.

Your slowness isn’t typical, but here are ways to reconfirm your diagnosis that sending a small amount of data to Apple’s servers to make a link to one or several photos isn’t network lag.

From a computer, use the web app to create a link. https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/share-photos-and-videos-mm93a9b98683/icloud
From the phone, start an edit on each photo to ensure it’s downloaded locally and that doesn’t slow things before creating a link.
Think about where your iCloud data is actually stored (EU, US, Asia, Mainland china, other…) and where your internet is to get to the server and back.
Keep notes and open a support case with Apple. They are the best place to know exactly where your photos are stored, if there are known issues or service configuration you can make to have a better experience.

For US based photos on several accounts with far slower “internet access” speeds than you list, operating on photos stored for a US based account, I can’t get more than 3 seconds of time elapsed for making a link to 10 items or fewer. Sometimes it’s slow with dozens of items, but usually faster than 30 seconds to a minute.
